# Extract data from Azure Logic App Request Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a pretty simple Azure Logic App.
I have a request trigger that has the following payload

```
{"first":"13", "second":"3"}
```

i've generated the schema with the designer

```
   {
  "properties": {
    "first": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "second": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "type": "object"
}
```

The i add a new step that sends a email, setting the subject to be the "first" parameter.

[image]

The problem I have is that the "first" (and the "second") parameter never appear to be set.
I get the email with the payload in the body, but the subject is empty, so the "first" parameter is not extracted, even though it certainly is present.

Anyone notice what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: In the request you're making to this Logic App, are you including header "Content-type: application/json"?

Comment: Thanks #Derek Li  such a simple solution. This is the correct answer, thanks very much!